# How to add custom fields to menu items

Tags: 7, routes

I've been looking at using [menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module for Drupal 7 to add an extra field to the menu navigation system. However this adds a new attribute to the attribute array and thus prints it out in the anchor link.

e.g.

```
  function themename_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below'])
  {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

  $subtitle = $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['subtitle']; //get sub text

  $linktext = $element['#title']. '<span>'. $subtitle .'</span>';
  $output = l($linktext, $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

But it comes out like this

```
<a subtitle="subtitleexampletext" href="/node/13">About us<span>subtitleexampletext</span></a>
```

is there anyway to hide the attribute in the link and just spit it out where ever I want it in the html? Or is there a better way of doing this? I've looked at [power menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/power_menu) module as well, but thats not quite what I'm after either.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter the menu link edit form. 
This way you can add a extra field to the form, in your case:

```
$form['subtitle'] = array(
 '#type'=>'textfield',
 '#title'=> t('Subtitle'),
);
```

Then add an extra submit hanlder to the form:

```
$form['#submit'][] = '_my_submit_handler';
```

In your submit handler you can access your custom value by using `$form_state['values']['subtitle'].`

You will have to store this value in an extra sql table or a variable_set,together with the menu-item ID.

Once you have done that, in your theme function you can access your subtitle by menu id.
Or you can use  `MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_link` to add extra info to $variables, which you then can access in your theme function.

Hopes this helpes you out.

Comment: Hi @Robin - thanks for your answer, I went with just using the menu_link function and used unset to remove the variable from the attributes array. Not ideal but at least gets the outcome I want.