# How to add fields to menu items

Tags: 8, navigation

I need to build a main menu that is a subset of the regular menu. The design team thinks it would be better for user to have only the most important links in the main menu and not have everything. Some links are top level menu and some are sub menus. For this I was hoping to be able to add a field to the menu link item form as a drop down. When creating a link the user could use this dropdown to "promoteToMainMenuAsBigLink" or "promoteToMainMenuAsSmallLink" or leave none to not show the item on the main menu.

I'm looking for a similar solution as this [Drupal 7 solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135326/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-menu-items) but for Drupal 8.

I was hoping to be able to add a column in the table menu_link_content_data beside 'expanded'. I was hoping not to have to record this information in an other table like shown in the d7 solution.

I was able to add a field to the link form in a custom module I build, just for test purpose I only added a text field to start with:

custom_menu.module:

```
function custom_menu_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form') {
    $form['promoteToMainMenu'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Promote to main menu'),
      '#description' => t('Promote link menu to main menu.'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#weight' => -9
    );
  }
}
```

The field is indeed shown in the link form but it is never recorded.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: As unlikely as it sounds, custom menu link items are content entities ( https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!menu_link_content!src!Entity!MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/8.2.x ). That means you need to use a hook to add the field (maybe https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info_alter/8.2.x ) and then run an update function to update the schema.

Answer (score 16):

Check the [Menu Item Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras) module.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, as of v2.0 of this module turns menu links into fully fieldable entites. Better solution than Colossal menu because it enhances the core menu system instead of replacing it.

Comment: +1 great for including today's date in the menu bar, for example

Comment: There is the article about all features https://lembergsolutions.com/blog/get-fieldable-drupal-menu-menu-item-extras-overview

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. You can only add additional fields to a menu, but you can't use existing fields that belong to the menu item entity?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `hook_entity_base_field_info` to add an additional field to the `menu_link_content` entity with the following code:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_base_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  $fields = [];

  if ($entity_type->id() == 'menu_link_content') {
    $fields['FIELD_NAME'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('FIELD_TYPE')
      ->setLabel(t('FIELD_LABEL'))
      ->setDescription(t('FIELD_DESCRIPTION '))
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', ['type' => 'FIELD_TYPE', 'weight' => 0]);
  }

  return $fields;
}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/defining-and-using-content-entity-field-definitions for more details on `BaseFieldDefinition`.

After which, you'll need `hook_form_menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form_alter()` to add a field to the form.

Comment: You do not have to add fields via form alter. You can simply use the `BaseFieldDefinition->setDisplayOptions()` method: `...->setDisplayOptions('form', [ ... ])`.

Comment: How I can create image field? I cannot find example with this field type and I need it. I can see image upload field when using this but when I try to save menu item I get: 
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_menu_image__target_id'

Also when I refresh page for add menu item form I see in logs: 
 Notice: Undefined index: field_menu_image__height
 Notice: Undefined index: field_menu_image__width 
and so on... Any example for image field type? Thanks

Comment: I've solved this problem.
/update.php is not working so column is never crated.
I've used drush to update db: drush updatedb --entity-updates

Comment: What do you put in hook_form_menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form_alter() to add the field?

Comment: i used this  but filed comes  on menus  but not store values i am using boolean filed  can anyone help me

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is indeed no fields UI for menu links by default in Drupal 8 as @MatthieuScarset said. But `menu_link_content` is a content entity in Drupal 8, so it is possible to add fields to it.

**Option #1** Of course you can do it programmatically as @Decipher suggested.

**Option #2** But there is another workaround to enable fields UI for menu links temporary:

1. Open `Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent`
2. Add `field_ui_base_route = "entity.menu.add_link_form"` to the
   annotation
3. Rebuild cache
4. Visit `/admin/structure/menu/manage/main/add/fields`
5. Manage all your fields, displays
6. Export your site configuration (`drush cex -y`).
7. Remove `field_ui_base_route = "entity.menu.add_link_form"` from the
   annotation at `Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent`
8. Rebuild cache.

Comment: I tried this approach. At first it looks good, but when I tried to create new field I get error: There was a problem creating field Menu image: Attempt to create a field 'field_menu_image' without a bundle.
I'm trying to achieve this programmatically now, but it would be better if this could work also.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Colossal Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/colossal_menu) to add the field instead of the core Menu module.

Answer (score 0):

"Menu item extras" is one way to achieve this, as @Mykhailo Gurei suggested.

But in my case I had to add extra fields and to use Mega menu module. I was using "We mega menu" and with it "Menu item extras" is not working. Simply menu is not shown on front-end (some templates override issue).

So other option that works with "We mega menu" is "Menu item content fields":

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_fields

Has the same functionality and doesn't have conflict with We mega menu module.

Answer (score 0):

A newer solution could be [menu item content fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_fields)

According to the project description its **features** are:

- Add fields to menu items and sort their display.
- Show fielded menu items with a block chosing the view mode.
- Configure additional options on the formatter like the rel and target attributes.
- Add more attributes with the Link attributes module.
- Optionally have a field on the menu link entity that overrides the display mode.

  - Is up to the site builder to create it.
  - This field needs to store the string value of the display mode, for example: 'mega'.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, Drupal 8 core developers have not made Menu links fieldable. 
So it is not possible to add fields to menu links for now.

The site builder "work around" is to create a custom vocabulary which can have custom fields.

Comment: Wrong. MenuLinkContent is a fieldable content entity.

Comment: How would you do to add new fields to MenuLinkContent?

Comment: see the answers above. They both explain how to add new fields to MenuLinkContent.

Comment: Menu Item Extras do that https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras

Comment: Ok, but MenuLinkContent is still NOT a fieldable content entity.

Comment: So to be clear @milkovsky 

True. MenuLinkContent is NOT a fieldable content entity.